# How to compute the composition of linear differential operator

Tags: differentials

For example, I have to write down the differential operator below as a polynomial in $\partial$
$$(\partial-f_n(x))(\partial-f_{n-1}(x))\cdots(\partial-f_1(x))$$where the product the the composition.
Specifically,
$$y_1 = x - \frac{m}{m+1},y_2=1,T_1=x^m(x-1),T_2=x^n$$
$$(\partial - D[y_1, x]/y_1)(\partial - D[T_1y_2/y_1, x]/(T_1y_2/y_1))(\partial - 
   D[T_1T_2y_1/y_2, x]/(T_1T_2y_2/y_2)) (\partial - 
   D[T_1^2T_2/y_1, x]/(T_1^2T_2/y_1))$$
Here $D[f,x]$ means $f'$.

I need the coefficients in $\partial$. And this is the simplest case that I will consider.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what $f_i(x)$ might be, and of what you expect to do with this?

Comment: @bill s $f_i$ are some rational functions in $x$, I need the coefficients in $\partial$. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please give a specific example of the $f_i$ and what you expect/hope to see as an output.

Comment: @bill s, I have given a specific example.

Comment: Related to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55182/factoring-a-differential-equation-into-an-operator-product including my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that $\partial$ in your question stands for the derivative with respect to `x`. Then you can directly use the method in [my linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5032/245) to solve this:

```
dx = Function[f, D[f, x]];
multiplyOp[scalar_, op_] := Function[{f1}, scalar op[f1]];
addOps[ops__] := Function[{f1}, Total@Map[#[f1] &, {ops}]];

CirclePlus[ops__] := addOps[ops];
CircleDot[scalar_, op_] := multiplyOp[scalar, op];
CircleTimes[ops__] := Composition[ops];

prod = (dx⊕f[2][x]⊙Identity)⊗(dx⊕f[1][x]⊙Identity);

CoefficientList[Simplify[prod[Exp[k x]]/Exp[k x]], k]
```

> $\left\{f(1)'(x)+f(1)(x) f(2)(x),f(1)(x)+f(2)(x),1\right\}$

Here I constructed the operator `prod` for example with two factors of the general type in the question. Then I apply `prod` to a test function `Exp[k x]` which has the property that every derivative pulls down a factor of `k`. To get the coefficients of the powers or the original $\partial$ operator, one therefore needs only to collect the powers of `k`. This is done by `CoefficientList` (with the lowest power first and the highest power last).